# Excel vba : Convert Unix Timestamp to Date Time

Tags: excel, vba

I know this has been asked quite a bit, but for some reason none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I have a unix time stamp (for example purposes use 1637402076084)

On my excel sheet I can convert that fine using
= (C2/ 86400000) + DATE(1970,1,1)
[image]

However I want to do this in my VBA code as there's a lot of data and I prefer doing it all in an array then applying my array to the sheet (for performance purposes)

However in my code I'm trying to use dateAdd

DateAdd("s", 1637402076084#, "1/1/1970 00:00:00")

but I get an overflow error

[image]

I'm assuming this is because the unix timestamp is too big? But it's one that gets returned from an api call and is a geniune one (as demonstrated by the formula) but I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of UNIX timestamps. 10 digits and **13 digits**. The function you try using is for 10 digits type. To convert the 13 digits type, you should create another function, exactly as you use in the cell:

```
Function fromUNIX13Digits(uT) As Date
   fromUNIX13Digits = CDbl(uT) / 86400000 + DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)
End Function
```

And test it as:

```
Sub testFromUNIX13()
      Debug.Print fromUNIX13Digits("1637402076084")
End Sub
```

For 10 digits type, you can use:

```
Public Function fromUnix10(ts) As Date
    fromUnix10 = DateAdd("s", CDbl(ts), "1/1/1970")
End Function
```

And test it using:

```
Sub testFromUnix10()
   Debug.Print fromUnix10("1651680385")
   Debug.Print Format(fromUnix10("1651680385"), "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")
End Sub
```

Or build a function able to deal with both types:

```
Function FromUNIX(uT) As Date
   If Len(uT) = 10 Then
        FromUNIX = DateAdd("s", CDbl(uT), "1/1/1970")
   ElseIf Len(uT) = 13 Then
        FromUNIX = CDbl(uT) / 86400000 + DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)
   Else
        MsgBox "No UNIX timestamp passed to be converted..."
   End If
End Function
```

And test it using:

```
Sub testFromUnix_()
 Dim x As String, y As String
 x = "1637402076084"
 y = "1651680385"
 Debug.Print FromUNIX(x)
 Debug.Print FromUNIX(y)
End Sub
```